# использование memcache в php

Tags: php, apache

Подскажите пожалуйста почему "вылетает" ошибка на этот код?

```
$memcache = new Memcache();
        $memcache->connect('127.0.0.1', 11211) or die("Could not connect");
```

и вот ошибка

Notice: Memcache::connect(): Server 127.0.0.1 (tcp 11211, udp 0) failed with: Connection refused (111) in /var/www/shop.localhost/trunk/modules/igor/content/test2.php on line 8

Warning: Memcache::connect(): Can't connect to 127.0.0.1:11211, Connection refused (111) in /var/www/shop.localhost/trunk/modules/igor/content/test2.php on line 8
Could not connect

Должно бы все работать. (разширение php5-memcache установлено)

Comment: translate.google.com: не удалось произвести подключение (код ошибки 111). Отдельно замечу, что кроме клиентского расширения должен работать и сам сервер memcache

Comment: @Etki поясните пожалуйста что это за сервер memcache? это как бы разширение php или еще что то  кроме него должно стоять?

Comment: помимо php расширения должен еще крутиться и сам memcache сервер, погуглите любой вариант "install memcache ubuntu-или-что-там-у-вас", через пакетные менеджеры поставится и стартанет в одну команду

Comment: @IgorKalamurda "это как бы разширение php или еще что то кроме него должно стоять?" - "кроме клиентского расширения должен работать и сам сервер memcache", ну ей-богу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

надо установить пакет `memcached`.

а если уже установлен, то выяснить, почему демон не запускается, либо, если запускаетеся, то почему не слушает свой стандартный порт.

начинать следует с просмотра `/var/log/syslog` на предмет информации от `memcached`.